# Выравние div-ов внутри div

Tags: html, css

Уважаемые знатоки, просьба помочь!

Есть несколько узких `div` со свойством `position:relative` (без `float`) внутри другого широкого `divX` со свойством `position:absolute`. Сейчас все внутренние `div` ровняются сверху вниз в одну колонку по левому краю и выходят за нижний край `divX`, а вся правая часть `divX` получается пустой.

Вопрос: какое кому свойсвто нужно задать, чтобы внутренние `div` ровнялись колонками и не выходили за нижнюю границу `divX` (чтобы на нижней границе `divX` был переход на новую колонку правее) ???

Только переход  не змейкой, а сверху вниз. Например, есть 9 дивов, нужно выровнять так:
1 колонка (левая) сверху вниз 1, 2, 3;
2 колонка (центральная) сверху вниз 4, 5, 6;
3 колонка (правая) сверху вниз 7, 8, 9.
Сейчас в одну колонку (левую) сверху вниз 1-9 и 4-9 вылезли за нижний край.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если устроит решение на CSS3, то смотрите [этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/bR5vX/2/). Там два варианта: с указанием кол-ва колонок и с "автоподбором", зависящим от указанной ширины колонок.